# How to clear file path history from the file explorer?

Tags: windows-vista

Under Microsoft Vista, the windows file explorer keeps paths and occasionally files in its history. This history can be seen by selecting the pull-down from the box at the top that keeps lists the current directory. I'd like to clear out that list, but I don't see an easy way to do it.

To clarify, I am talking about the file explorer (explorer.exe), not Internet Explorer (iexplorer.exe).

Comment: I'm sure you mean that you want to do this programmatically, so this would then be a programming related question?

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking Programming questions. You may be able to get help with this at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, even though you say you mean the file explorer and not internet explorer, you are almost on the right track there. If you delete your internet explorer history, it will also delete the file history in the explorer.

Bart

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is way to do this using built-in MS tools but with my XP box to clear things like file paths in explorer I use something called Crap Cleaner (http://ccleaner.com) -- wipes any windows searches / prefetch data / bad reg keys etc.

I do not know however if it works / performs the same with Vista.

- Nicholas